# Checking background color of view in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Say for example I have a white background, then on every time the view is touched, a blue box sized (60x60) is added to the screen. If i keep tapping all over the screen until the entire view becomes blue, how can I use code to notify the user using for example an alert controller saying that the view has now changed color completely.

if that made sense to anyone, I would appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: Do the boxes snap to a position? IE If i tap (20,40) will it fill from (0,0) to (60,60) or will it fill from (20-30,40-30) to (20+30,40+30)?

Comment: @milo526 yes the boxes appear on the same position you tap on, to eventually fill the screen once you've tapped everywhere.

Comment: @Zouvv then you can do as @milo256 said , you can think in the screen as a table of NxM where each square is of 60x60 as where `true` if the cell is marked or `false` otherwise, and when all the cells are marked show your alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, the best approach is to hold a reference to a 2D array to correlate with the UI. I would approach this by first:

1) Create a subclass of `UIView` called `overlayView`. This will be the view overlay on top of your View Controllers' `view`. This subclass will override `init(frame: CGRect)`. You may implement a NxM grid on initialization. You will also create and add the subviews as appropriate.

Example:

```
let boxWidth: CGFloat = 60
let boxHeight: CGFloat = 60
let boxFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600)

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: boxFrame)
    for i in 1 ... 10 {   //row
        for j in 1...10 {   //column
            let xCoordinate: CGFloat = CGFloat(CGFloat(i) * boxWidth)
            let yCoordinate: CGFloat = CGFloat(CGFloat(j) * boxHeight)
            let boxFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: xCoordinate, y: yCoordinate, width: boxWidth, height: boxHeight)
            var subView: UIView = UIView(frame: boxFrame)
            subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            self.addSubview(subView)
        }
    }
}
```

2) Override `touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)` within `overlayView`. The implementation should look something like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch: UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        let touchLocation: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self)

        for subView in self.subviews {
            if(CGRectContainsPoint(subView.frame, touchLocation)) {
                subView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
}
```

2a) You will also want to create a function to notify your 2D array that this subview as been removed. This will be called from within your `if` statement. In addition, this function will detect if the array is empty (all values set to `false`)

OR

2b) if you do not need a reference to the model (you do not care which boxes are tapped only that they're all gone), you can skip 2a and check if `self.subviews.count == 0`. If this is the case, you do not need a 2D array at all. If this condition passes, you can present an alert to the user as needed.

3) Create an `overlayView` in your main View Controller and add it as a subview.

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time to do all of this, it helped me. truly appreciate it !